# Trying to create xml in c# from xml schema using XDocument and XmlSchemaSet

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create a xml document that need to be serialized against some xml schemas. This is the result now

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StandardBusinessDocument>
  <StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
    <HeaderVersion>1,0</HeaderVersion>
    <Sender>
      <Identifier>5790000011032</Identifier>
    </Sender>
    <Receiver>
      <Identifier>5790000500000</Identifier>
    </Receiver>
    <DocumentIdentification>
      <Standard>EAN.UCC</Standard>
      <TypeVersion>2.8</TypeVersion>
      <InstanceIdentifier>DI-35346-34535-xt435345</InstanceIdentifier>
      <Type>catalogueItemNotification</Type>
      <CreationDateAndTime>2013-12-20T10:46:26+00:00</CreationDateAndTime>
    </DocumentIdentification>
  </StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
</StandardBusinessDocument>
```

And here is what it should look like.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sh:StandardBusinessDocument xmlns:sh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" xmlns:eanucc="urn:ean.ucc:2" xmlns:gdsn="urn:ean.ucc:gdsn:2" xmlns:align="urn:ean.ucc:align:2" xmlns:chemical_ingredient="urn:ean.ucc:align:chemical_ingredient:2" xmlns:food_beverage_tobacco="urn:ean.ucc:align:food_beverage_tobacco:2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/sbdh/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/CatalogueItemNotificationProxy.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/AttributeValuePairExtensionProxy.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/CaseLevelNonGTINLogisticsUnitExtensionProxy.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/TradeItemExtensionSpecificsProxy.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/ChemicalIngredientExtensionProxy.xsd urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/FoodAndBeverageTradeItemExtensionProxy.xsd">

    <sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
        <sh:HeaderVersion>1.0</sh:HeaderVersion>
        <sh:Sender>
            <sh:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">5790000011032</sh:Identifier>
        </sh:Sender>
        <sh:Receiver>
            <sh:Identifier Authority="EAN.UCC">5790000500000</sh:Identifier>
        </sh:Receiver>
        <sh:DocumentIdentification>
            <sh:Standard>EAN.UCC</sh:Standard>
            <sh:TypeVersion>2.8</sh:TypeVersion>
            <sh:InstanceIdentifier>DI-35346-34535-xt435345</sh:InstanceIdentifier>
            <sh:Type>catalogueItemNotification</sh:Type>
            <sh:CreationDateAndTime>2013-12-20T10:46:26+00:00</sh:CreationDateAndTime>
        </sh:DocumentIdentification>
    </sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
    </sh:StandardBusinessDocument>
```

What i have so far in the method where i create the xml is this.

```
XmlSchemaSet sbdSchema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd");
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\DocumentIdentification.xsd");
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\BasicTypes.xsd");
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\BusinessScope.xsd");
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\Manifest.xsd");
        sbdSchema.Add("http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader", "D:\\Europoultry\\Program\\EPWCF\\EPSystem\\EPSystem\\XMLSchemas\\sdbh\\Partner.xsd");

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("StandardBusinessDocument",
        new XElement("StandardBusinessDocumentHeader",
            new XElement("HeaderVersion", "1,0"),
            new XElement("Sender",
                new XElement("Identifier", "5790000011032")),
        new XElement("Receiver",
            new XElement("Identifier", "5790000500000")),
        new XElement("DocumentIdentification",
            new XElement("Standard", "EAN.UCC"),
            new XElement("TypeVersion", "2.8"),
            new XElement("InstanceIdentifier", "DI-35346-34535-xt435345"),
            new XElement("Type", "catalogueItemNotification"),
            new XElement("CreationDateAndTime", "2013-12-20T10:46:26+00:00")
        )))
      );

        var savePath = "C:\\GS1TradeSyncItem.xml";
        doc.Save(savePath);
```

I dont think the schemas is being importet right since the element dont have some attibutes on them, but i am not sure if this is what the problem is. Hope one of you can help. 
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a schema for generating a XML.  The schema is just used for validating the data.  You can verify the generated xml with the schema.  There are tools on web that can do the verification.  One you verified the xml once it no necessary to validate every time, but you can.  One way is to read the xml back into your application verifying with the schema.

Comment: @jdweng yes i know that is is not neccesary to have a schema for creating  the xml. But i need the schemas since the xml needs to be validatet so that i can send it to another system. And that other system needs the xml to be in a format so that their system understands it.

Comment: I just meant when generating the xml it isn't needed in the code.  Once the xml is generated then validate against schema to check for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would add the namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string savePath = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string identification =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?> " +
                "<sh:StandardBusinessDocument" +
                   " xmlns:sh=\"http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader\"" +
                   " xmlns:eanucc=\"urn:ean.ucc:2\" " +
                   " xmlns:gdsn=\"urn:ean.ucc:gdsn:2\" " +
                   " xmlns:align=\"urn:ean.ucc:align:2\" " +
                   " xmlns:chemical_ingredient=\"urn:ean.ucc:align:chemical_ingredient:2\" " +
                   " xmlns:food_beverage_tobacco=\"urn:ean.ucc:align:food_beverage_tobacco:2\"" +
                   " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                   " xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/sbdh/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/CatalogueItemNotificationProxy.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/AttributeValuePairExtensionProxy.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/CaseLevelNonGTINLogisticsUnitExtensionProxy.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/TradeItemExtensionSpecificsProxy.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/ChemicalIngredientExtensionProxy.xsd" +
                   " urn:ean.ucc:2 http://www.gdsregistry.org/2.8/schemas/FoodAndBeverageTradeItemExtensionProxy.xsd\"" +
                "/>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(identification);
            XElement standardBusinessDocument = doc.Root;
            XNamespace sh = standardBusinessDocument.Name.Namespace;

            standardBusinessDocument.Add(
                    new XElement(sh + "StandardBusinessDocumentHeader",
                    new XElement(sh + "HeaderVersion", "1.0"),
                    new XElement(sh + "Sender",
                    new XElement(sh + "Identifier", new object[] {new XAttribute("Authority","EAN.UCC"), "5790000011032"})),
                    new XElement(sh + "Receiver",
                    new XElement(sh + "Identifier", new object[] {new XAttribute("Authority","EAN.UCC"), "5790000500000"})), 
                    new XElement(sh + "DocumentIdentification",
                    new XElement(sh + "Standard", "EAN.UCC"),
                    new XElement(sh + "TypeVersion", "2.8"),
                    new XElement(sh + "InstanceIdentifier", "DI-35346-34535-xt435345"),
                    new XElement(sh + "Type", "catalogueItemNotification"),
                    new XElement(sh + "CreationDateAndTime", "2013-12-20T10:46:26+00:00")
                ))
            );

            doc.Save(savePath);
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on the namespace part. But for some reason the attributes is till not getting on the elements? if you look at the `<Identifier>5790000011032</Identifier>` it is still missing the Authority="EAN.UCC" attribute.

Comment: Header version also need to be change from comma 1,0 to period 1.0

Comment: Thanks you ! works perfect. Do you know if it is possible to auto generate the attributes from the schema?

Comment: Aren't the attribute values going to change?  Some items in the schema are optional and I don't think you want to include all optional parameters.  Results could be very large.

Comment: it would make best sense to do it like the answer, did not think of that the attributes maybe need to change at some point. So i think the best solution is this way. It was just fun to know if it was possible to auto generate it.